# PIG field_name MATCHES string

Tags: parsing, apache-pig, arrays

say field_1 MATCHES 'a_string'
I would like select any entries with field_1 CONTAINING(if this exist) 'string' so that field_1 with 'a_string' will be included.

For an example

Entry  Field_1

1. 'a_string'
2. 'string'
3. 'strang'

Entries 1 and 2 will be selected.

May I know what is the most elegant way to do this?

The actual strings(chararray) I am dealing with are urls with different levels of depth i.e. www.abc.com/depth1/depth2/...

I was planning to parse the chararray using '/' as delimitter but its just too ugly. I will need to change the number for columns should a inner depth appeared.

Your assistance is deeply appreciated!!

Comment: use X = FILTER A BY (Field_1 matches '.*string.*');

Comment: was any of this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I think you can use the filter operation with matches for this. The second parameter is a regular expression.

X = FILTER A BY (field_1 matches '.*a_string.*');

See the [Docs](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html) for more detail.